# Google Sheets Formula Assistance - Matching Names to List of Data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have a bank export that removes the category of the spend. To reconcile my budget to my categories I'd like to run the list of Descriptions the bank provides to match them against my list of categories.

Example list of Descriptions matched to my Categories:

- ACH XXX9797 Google Bill --> Electronics
- XXXX12345 Citi ---> Credit
- Card XXXX456894 Chase ---> Credit Card
- XXXX858035 Target ----> Grocery

I also need it to be flexible enough so when it doesn't find a match it leaves the cell blank.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a table of keywords and respective categories (see green table) and then use regex with `VLOOKUP` to match it. formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A&"", 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(Sheet1!F2:F, 1, 0)))), Sheet1!F2:G, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]